Cannot find module 'ajv/dist/compile/codegen' error in containerised React app in Azure App Service build
I have a React app that is being deployed in Azure App Service through the Azure container registry so it is using a Docker image.
It has been working up until last week when the startup of the app is failing due to the error Cannot find module 'ajv/dist/compile/codegen'.
The app starts fine locally, using both npm start and a docker image so it is just happening when I am trying to deploy through the app service.
Output from command npm list ajv. Note all of these are dependencies of libraries I am using, I do not directly use this package.
── ajv@8.13.0
└─┬ react-scripts@5.0.1
  ├─┬ @pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin@0.5.15
  │ └─┬ schema-utils@4.2.0
  │   ├─┬ ajv-formats@2.1.1
  │   │ └── ajv@8.13.0 deduped
  │   ├─┬ ajv-keywords@5.1.0
  │   │ └── ajv@8.13.0 deduped
  │   └── ajv@8.13.0 deduped
  ├─┬ babel-loader@8.3.0
  │ └─┬ schema-utils@2.7.1
  │   ├─┬ ajv-keywords@3.5.2
  │   │ └── ajv@6.12.6 deduped
  │   └── ajv@6.12.6
  ├─┬ eslint@8.57.0
  │ ├─┬ @eslint/eslintrc@2.1.4
  │ │ └── ajv@6.12.6
  │ └── ajv@6.12.6
  ├─┬ file-loader@6.2.0
  │ └─┬ schema-utils@3.3.0
  │   ├─┬ ajv-keywords@3.5.2
  │   │ └── ajv@6.12.6 deduped
  │   └── ajv@6.12.6
  ├─┬ react-dev-utils@12.0.1
  │ └─┬ fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin@6.5.3
  │   └─┬ schema-utils@2.7.0
  │     ├─┬ ajv-keywords@3.5.2
  │     │ └── ajv@6.12.6 deduped
  │     └── ajv@6.12.6
  ├─┬ terser-webpack-plugin@5.3.10
  │ └─┬ schema-utils@3.3.0
  │   ├─┬ ajv-keywords@3.5.2
  │   │ └── ajv@6.12.6 deduped
  │   └── ajv@6.12.6
  ├─┬ webpack@5.91.0
  │ └─┬ schema-utils@3.3.0
  │   ├─┬ ajv-keywords@3.5.2
  │   │ └── ajv@6.12.6 deduped
  │   └── ajv@6.12.6
  └─┬ workbox-webpack-plugin@6.6.0
    └─┬ workbox-build@6.6.0
      ├─┬ @apideck/better-ajv-errors@0.3.6
      │ └── ajv@8.13.0 deduped
      └── ajv@8.13.0 deduped

This is my docker file, I have tried multiple versions of ajv installation but none have worked.
FROM node:20.11-alpine
WORKDIR /frontend
COPY . .
COPY .babelrc /frontend
RUN npm config set legacy-peer-deps true
RUN npm install --legacy-peer-deps
RUN npm install --force
RUN npm install ajv@8.13.0 ajv-keywords@3 --force
RUN npm install @azure/msal-browser --legacy-peer-deps
RUN npm install @azure/msal-react --legacy-peer-deps
RUN npm install @material-ui/core --force
RUN npm install @babel/preset-react --force
RUN npm install @babel/preset-env --force
RUN npm install -g react-scripts
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["sh", "-c", "npm install && npm run start"]

Tried this answer
Also deleted node_modules and package-lock.json to run a fresh install but this has not worked either.
Is there anything I am missing or need to do to get this resolved?

Did you try downgrading the ajv package version?

Yes i have tried different versions which has not worked. Is there a proper method to working out what version should be compatible or is it just trial and error?

Run this command npm ls ajv, it points to the specific version of ajv required for your app.

I have done that, as seen in my question and tried all kinds of variations of versions. What I do not understand is the project is working locally, both with npm start and within a docker image but the exact same docker image, built using the same dockerfile results in an error within Azure.

Please share your GitHub repo if possible.

I can see you are trying to install ajv@8.13.0 and ajv-keywords@3 in the docker file.

But as mentioned in the article, you need to install ajv-keywords@5.*.* when ajv version 8.*.* is being used.

If the ajv package version 6.*.*, you can install ajv-keywords@3.*.* .




The same has been available in the provided output of npm list ajv:

── ajv@8.13.0
└─┬ react-scripts@5.0.1
  ├─┬ @pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin@0.5.15
  │ //Removed few modules
  │   ├─┬ ajv-keywords@5.1.0

  ├─┬ babel-loader@8.3.0
  │ └─┬ schema-utils@2.7.1
  │   ├─┬ ajv-keywords@3.5.2
  │   │ └── ajv@6.12.6 deduped
  │   └── ajv@6.12.6
  │ ////Removed few modules


Remove force and use Save instead in the command in Docker File.

npm install ajv@8.13.0 ajv-keywords@5.1.0 --Save


I have created a react app and used below code in Dockerfile:
# Fetching the latest node image on alpine linux
FROM node:alpine AS development

# Installing dependencies
COPY package*.json .

RUN npm install

# Copying all the files in our project
COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

# Starting our application
CMD ["npm","start"]


Installed latest packages of ajv(8.16.0) and ajv-keywords(5.0.1).




I have a solution that appears to have worked. I added the line below in dockerfile to install the package globally in the container which has let react-scripts find it.
RUN npm install -g ajv@8.13.0
Thanks everyone for suggestions, I had tried loads of different combinations of versions with no luck but this has removed the error.
